# IIS rewrite URL in asp.net goes to into infinity loop

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, web-config, webmatrix

I just need to create a rule in my web config file to rewrite all URLs to given into rule

ex:
url/services/presentations-evenementielles to
url/Services/Presentations-Evenementielles

This is all made for SEO purposes to avoid duplicates.

```
<rule name="ProductionRule2" stopProcessing="true" patternSyntax="ExactMatch" >
                <match url="^/productions/xyz" ignoreCase="true" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="Productions/XYZ" redirectType="Permanent"/>
              </rule>
```

Above code its gives me infinite loop error.

Comment: If you're ignoring the case, then of course it's going to result in an infinite loop because it will keep matching to the same value if the only thing you do is change the case.

Comment: @mason, can you please provide rule, so that i can implement it

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules Learn how to debug. BTW, the match pattern can be wrong.

Comment: currently, this rule is working fine if redirection URL is different one. If redirection URL as per given URL then its goes to redirect loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was some mistakes with your rule

1.You were trying to use "^" in an exact match rule. Please set it to regular expression

2.You are trying to use "/" in match url.  The match url part of domain/productions/xyz is
productions/xyz instead of /production/xyz.

3.You are enabling ignore case when you redirect URL to itself.

So please try to modify the rule like this

```
<rule name="ProductionRule2" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^productions/xyz" ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="Productions/XYZ" redirectType="Permanent" />
              </rule>
```

Update:

Please modify the rule like this

```
<rule name="ProductionRule2" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^Productions/XYZ" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="Productions/XYZ" redirectType="Permanent" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{ToLower:{URL}}" pattern="/productions/xyz" />
                    </conditions>
              </rule>
```

And this is working on my side
[image]

Please remember to clean browser cache when you test the rule.And the URL should be prODuctions/Xyz instead of prODuction/Xyz.

Comment: Hi, Its working fine but if in my url is like prODuction/Xyz then is not working.

Comment: @BrijeshPatel. I think you can change the condition pattern to "doesn't match Productions/XYZ"  and enable ignoreCase.

Comment: So how to add condition of doesn't match? and keeping ignoreCase="false"

Comment: Please just try <match url="^Productions/XYZ" ignoreCase="false" negate="true"  />

Comment: No for this its not working its again goes to infinity loop.

Comment: @BrijeshPatel I  just update the rule. Please check whether it achieve your requirement.

Comment: if we adding 40 50 rules in web.config then its any affect to performance on server

Comment: @BrijeshPatel. IIS rewrite module will match the rule one by one until a rule get matched. So you'd better to adjust your rewrite rule to let each request pass the least rules.

Comment: So, In web.config i have multiple rewrite rules(I had set 40 rules in web.config) are ex, 1) Production/Xyz 2) Productions/AbC. So all of pages has different uppercase lowercase combination.So here i must need to create 2 rules because is there no way to create regax or any condition to handle this scenario. Yoh have any way to achieve this with one rule?

Comment: I think you shouldn't to create so much rules to fix this issue.The problem can be easily fixed in application level instead of URL rewrite level.